# optaplanner immovable planning entities

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm working with Optaplanner to solve a problem similar to the patient admission scheduling example.

I'm facing two problems.

Firstly when one of the planning entities (similar to bedDesignation of the example) is positioned by someone (not optaplanner), this planning entity is scored like the others. 
The planning entity manually placed become an immovable planning entity but it is still scored like movable planning entity. And because of that it breaks some hard constraint.

Secondly still when one of the planning entities (similar to bedDesignation) is positioned by someone (not optaplanner), this planning entity is moved during the local search phase.
The local search phase is configured like this (same configuration than the example) :

```
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <moveListFactory>
        <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.pas.solver.move.factory.BedDesignationPillarPartSwapMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
      </moveListFactory>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
      <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
```

The BedDesignationPillarPartSwapMoveFactory class is unchanged from the example.
I read in the documentation that for an immovable planning entities we must make sure that the custom moveListFactory don't move immovable entities. But how ? In the config xml file or in the class itself ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `BedDesignationPillarPartSwapMoveFactory` to skip entities (`BedDesignations`) that aren't movable (for example if they are `isLocked() == true`).

Or better yet: don't use BedDesignationPillarPartSwapMoveFactory at all, just go with generic move selectors: changeMove, swapMove, pillarChangeMove and pillarSwapMove. The pillar moves now select subpillars in 6.2, but I haven't tested yet if this gives better results on that example (I believe it will) - which could make the custom move factory obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have change the configuration file to work with generic move. The immovable planning entities are now really immovable.

But which configuration for the unionMoveSelector is better (changeMove, swapMove, pillarChangeMove or pillarSwapMove) ?

However, the problem of the score is still there. The immovable planning entities are scored like movable entities.

Comment: Does it matter that immovable entities are score like movable entities? It's a fixed cost that never changes during planning, so it doesn't change the best found solution if it wasn't there. Furthermore, consider the score constraint that no 2 entities should conflict. If 1 is immovable and the other is not, you 'll still want it to trigger.

Comment: As for which config is better, see chapter about the Benchmarker (and my recent video on youtube about it).

Comment: About the best configuration it was in case you know one for this kind of problem.
I'm already trying the benchmarker, I will check your video.

Comment: About the score of immovable entities, I thought it was possible to not score the immovable entities but when scoring the other entities take into account the immovable entities.
I've got a simple case where a human places an entity where it breaks one or more hard constraint.
In that case, whatever the result obtained by optaplanner, one or more hard constraint will be broken. It will result in a score like this -XX Hard/-YY Medium/-ZZ Soft.
So do I need to understand that this score is the best score and indeed this solution is the best ?